# unwanted close confirmation box when a user submited an Html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, dialog

when a user is closing a tab or closing browser, i wanna ask a confirmation question! so i used this in my form:

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                return "You're leaving the site.";
            };
```

but when user is call s.t or submit by a button or enter in a text box the dialog appears again! i could prevent to appears in button submit but the problem is text box post backs! how can i prevent onbeforeunload to happen when a text box sends a post back?
the codes that i tried"

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $('a[rel!=ext]').click(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
                $('form').submit(function () { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
            });
```

AND this

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="setFormSubmitting()">     
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

...........

```
var formSubmitting = false;
var setFormSubmitting = function() { formSubmitting = true; };

window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if (formSubmitting) {
            return undefined;
        }

        var confirmationMessage = 'It looks like you have been editing something. '
                                + 'If you leave before saving, your changes will be lost.';

        (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage; //Gecko + IE
        return confirmationMessage; //Gecko + Webkit, Safari, Chrome etc.
    });
};
```